# how to join multiple tables in update statement of mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, join, sql-update

i have tables my_employees,my_departments , my_emp_details , my_periods
and below query is in oracle's old join statement I want to convert this in mysql syntax and I am not able to do it please help

```
UPDATE my_employees a SET 
                               a.attribute1, a.attribute2, a.attribute3, a.attribute4,
                               a.attribute5, a.attribute6, a.attribute7, a.attribute8,
                               a.attribute9, a.attribute10, a.attribute11, a.attribute12,
                               a.attribute13, a.attribute14, a.attribute15, a.attribute16,
                               a.attribute17, a.attribute18, a.attribute19, a.attribute20 = 
                        (SELECT b.attribute1, b.attribute2, b.attribute3, b.attribute4,
                               b.attribute5, b.attribute6, b.attribute7, b.attribute8,
                               b.attribute9, b.attribute10, b.attribute11, b.attribute12,
                               b.attribute13, b.attribute14, b.attribute15, b.attribute16,
                               b.attribute17, b.attribute18, b.attribute19, b.attribute20
                          FROM my_departments b, my_emp_details c, my_periods p
                         WHERE b.dept_seq_id(+) = c.dept_seq_id
                           AND a.person_seq_id = c.person_seq_id
                           AND c.period_seq_id = p.period_seq_id
                           AND p.period_status = 'CURRENT')
                         WHERE a.person_seq_id = l_person_seq_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE my_employees a  
INNER JOIN my_departments b ON a.person_seq_id = b.person_seq_id 
INNER JOIN my_emp_details c ON b.dept_seq_id = c.dept_seq_id
INNER JOIN my_periods p ON c.period_seq_id = p.period_seq_id AND p.period_status = 'CURRENT' 
SET a.attribute1 = b.attribute1, a.attribute2 = b.attribute2, a.attribute3 = b.attribute3, 
     a.attribute4 = b.attribute4, a.attribute5 = b.attribute5, a.attribute6 = b.attribute6, 
     a.attribute7 = b.attribute7, a.attribute8 = b.attribute8, a.attribute9 = b.attribute9, 
     a.attribute10 = b.attribute10, a.attribute11 = b.attribute11, a.attribute12 = b.attribute12, 
     a.attribute13 = b.attribute13, a.attribute14 = b.attribute14, a.attribute15 = b.attribute15, 
     a.attribute16 = b.attribute16, a.attribute17 = b.attribute17, a.attribute18 = b.attribute18, 
     a.attribute19 = b.attribute19, a.attribute20 = b.attribute20;
```

Comment: in Update statement I think there wont be from keyword please check it once